# lmer Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object x not found

Tags: r, lme4

Applying `lmer()` function across all columns in dataframe. I have made a list of variables and used `lapply`. Below is the code:

```
varlist=names(Genus_abundance)[5:ncol(Genus_abundance)]

lapply(varlist, function(x){lmer(substitute(i ~ Status + (1|Match), list(i=as.name(x), data=Genus_abundance, na.action = na.exclude)))})
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
 Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Acetatifactor' not found
```

I have checked and Acetatifactor is in the `Genus_abundance` dataframe.
Bit stuck about where its going wrong

EDIT:
Added a working example:

```
set.seed(43)
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, Status=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2), age= sample(18:90, n, replace=TRUE), match=1:n, Acetatifactor=runif(n), Acutalibacter=runif(n), Adlercreutzia=runif(n))

head(dat)
id Status age match Acetatifactor Acutalibacter Adlercreutzia
1  1      A  49     1     0.1861022     0.1364904     0.8626298
2  2      B  31     2     0.7297301     0.8246794     0.3169752
3  3      A  23     3     0.4118721     0.5923042     0.2592606
4  4      B  64     4     0.4140497     0.7943970     0.7422665
5  5      A  60     5     0.4803101     0.7690324     0.7473611
6  6      B  79     6     0.4274945     0.9180564     0.9179040
```

Comment: To get a great answer quickly, include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Even better - try this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295957/r-loop-multiple-independent-variables-through-a-mixed-effect-model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
lapply(varlist,
       function(x){lmer(substitute(i ~ status + (1|match), list(i=as.name(x))),
   data=dd)
})
```

The specific problem here is misplaced parentheses. You should close the `substitute(..., list(i=as.name(x)))` with three close-parentheses so that the whole chunk is properly understood as the *first* argument to `lme4`.

More generally I agree with @Kat in the comments that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295957/r-loop-multiple-independent-variables-through-a-mixed-effect-model) is a good place to look. Since your arguments are already strings (not symbols) you don't really need all of the `substitute()` business and could use

```r
fit_fun <- function(v) {
   lmer(reformulate(c("status", "(1|match)"), response = v),
        data = dd, na.action = na.exclude)
}
lapply(varlist, fit_fun)
```

Or you could use `refit` to fit the first column, then update the fit with each of the next columns. For large models this is much more efficient.

```r
m1 <- lmer(resp1 ~ status + (1|match), ...)
m_other <- lapply(dd[-(1:3)], refit, object = m1)
c(list(m1), m_other)
```

Comment: Thank you, I see the issue ```list()``` was part of the first argument of lmer

Comment: Great. I do recommend taking at look at the other solutions provided here - IMO they're more robust and more efficient than your current setup with `substitute` etc. (although I agree that your current setup should work fine if you don't have complicated workflow and your data are not large)

Comment: @BenBolker Where does the "here" refer to?

Comment: "here" means "in this answer". (i.e., I'm encouraging the OP to look beyond the proximal fix-my-parentheses solution I provided first, to the other solutions provided)